# For-loop/if -statement with character range

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, append

I'm creating a for loop with an if statement to append a value to a new variable if a specific condition is met. I did the same thing earlier, without the character range of `i`, and it worked fine. When I try the code below, it doesn't work and shoots out 'KeyError: 0', which doesn't make sense because `merge_image1` is a list and not a dictionary.

Hope someone is able to help out!

`behav_op1` and `merge_image1` are both lists, where each element is a image file pathway (string).

This is the code that is doing the same thing, minus the character range, but for a different variable and works fine:

```
for i in behav_op1:
   if i == 'Stimuli/Operations (Post-study)/main.png':
       behav_opIdentity1.append('maintain')
   elif i == 'Stimuli/Operations (Post-study)/supp.png':
       behav_opIdentity1.append('suppress')
```

This is the code causing the issue:

```
for i in merge_image1:
   if i[0:36] == 'Stimuli/Faces/resized_positive_faces':
       image_valence1.append('positive')
   elif i[0:31] == 'Sitmuli/Faces/resized_neg_faces':
       image_valence.append('negative')
```

Comment: Which line is getting that error?

Comment: What type are the elements of the list?

Comment: FYI, you can simplify the code using `if i.startswith(...)`. Then you don't need to count the number of characters for the slice.

Comment: "which doesn't make sense because merge_image1 is a list and not a dictionary." It makes perfect sense, because the error message is telling you about `i`, not about `merge_image1`, and because `i` is a dictionary. The reason that `i` is a dictionary is that `merge_image1` is a list **of dictionaries**. This should be clear if you read (and show) a [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error message, copied and pasted, starting from the line that says `Traceback (most recent call last):` until the end and formatted like code; but in the code shown, only `i` is indexed.

Comment: That said: if you used the *normal* way to check "does the string start with X?", i.e. the `startswith` method, then you would get a different error message which would hopefully also be more clear.

Comment: ```i``` is a string in this case, the elements in ```merge_image1``` are all strings. I edited my post with the Traceback that caused the KeyError.

Comment: Add `print(type(i))` as the first statement in the loop and quadruple check that it is what you expect it to be.

Comment: I put ```print(type(i))``` as the first statement in the for-loop and it's a string.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess, `KeyError: 0` is raised in line

```
if i[0:36] == 'Stimuli/Faces/resized_positive_faces':
```

where you're giving `0` as a key for `i`. if `i` were a `String`, this should probably work. However, it looks like the elements of `merge_image1` aren't  just `String`s, but they are accessed through a key. A key generally needs to be a `String` itself instead of an `int` like `0`.

The solution is to double check the type of `i` and access it according to its type. For instance, if `i` is a `dict` (a classical example of a container accessed by a key) consisting of a single pair, you'll need to do something like

```
if list(i.keys())[0][0:36] == 'Stimuli/Faces/resized_positive_faces':
```

or (better) use `startswith` suggested in the comments,

```
if list(i.keys())[0].startswith('Stimuli/Faces/resized_positive_faces'):
```

BTW if you want to check the type of `i`, just do

```
print(merge_image1[0])
```

If this fails because of indexing issues, then the whole code should be probably be rewritten to work with whatever `merge_image1` type is.

Comment: ```i``` is a string and the elements in ```merge_image1``` are strings. That's the weird thing, I performed the same kind of loop to create another variable, without the character range. At first I got the same KeyError, and then I added the for loop to the if-statements. So I'm very confused what the issue is. I coded this same thing in Sublime and it worked fine, but I'm programming it in Python through PsychoPy and that's where I'm having the issue.

Comment: for i in behav_op1:
    if i == 'Stimuli/Operations (Post-study)/main.png':
        behav_opIdentity1.append('maintain')
    elif i == 'Stimuli/Operations (Post-study)/supp.png':
        behav_opIdentity1.append('suppress')

Comment: ^ This is what worked previously.

Comment: Maybe it'd be easier if you could update your question with a working code so we can debug it.

Comment: I updated my post with the chunk that was working, in addition to the one causing the issue.

Comment: We can't reproduce your issues if we don't have the definitions of `behav_op1` and `merge_image1` to test them...

Comment: both ```behav_op1``` and ```merge_image1``` are lists where each element is an image pathway string